# Counting words in an input string in C++ **with consideration for typos

Tags: c++, string, split, count, substring

I've been looking for ways to count the number of words in a string, but specifically for strings that may contain typos (i.e. "_This_is_a___test" as opposed to "This_is_a_test"). Most of the pages I've looked at only handle single spaces.

**This is actually my first time programming in C++**, and I don't have much other programming experience to speak of (2 years of college in C and Java). Although what I have is functional, I'm also aware it's complex, and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same results?

This is what I have currently. Before I run the string through numWords(), I run it through a trim function that removes leading whitespace, then check that there are still characters remaining.

```
int numWords(string str) {
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == '\n') {
            bool repeat = true;
            int j = 1;
            while (j < (str.size() - i) && repeat) {
                if (str[i + j] != ' ' && str[i + j] != '\t' && str[i + j] != '\n') {
                    repeat = false;
                    i = i + j;
                    count++;
                }
                else
                    j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also, I wrote mine to take a string argument, but most of the examples I've seen used (char* str) instead, which I wasn't sure how to use with my input string.

Comment: Use `std::istringstream` -- it does the space-checking automatically.

Comment: you only need to count `space-char` sequence.

Comment: This task should take about six lines of code. A single loop, two variables, and three or four lines of logic. No need for any expensive stringstream objects, that involve dynamic memory allocation and all that overhead. Just one loop.

Comment: Just count non-space characters if they are at the start of the string, or if they are preceded by a space. That's a simple loop. Your solution is far too complex.

Comment: `if (str[i + j] != ' ' && str[i + j] != '\t' && str[i + j] != '\n')` -- If you're going to check for spaces, the `std::isspace` function should be used.  You are missing characters like vertical tab, for example (and any others that `std::isspace` considers a space character).

Comment: Either use `std::istringstream` (which handles whitespace by default) or, if your code encounters whitespace, simply skip any immediately following whitespace.   Practically, whitespace isn't usually considered a typo - it is just skipped or used as needed.  Typos normally describe things like typing "Dig" instead of "Dog", and the rules for detecting/correcting for such things are more complicated/specialised than handling of whitespace (e.g. grammar and spelling correction).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all those `stringstream`s to count word boundary

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int numWords(std::string str) 
{   
    bool space = true; // not in word
    int count = 0;
    for(auto c:str){
        if(std::isspace(c))space=true;
        else{
            if(space)++count;
            space=false;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to utilize [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to count the number of words and to skip over spaces automatically.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int numWords(std::string str) 
{
    int count = 0;
    std::istringstream strm(str);
    std::string word;
    while (strm >> word)
      ++count;
   return count;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << numWords("  This    is a test  ");
}
```

Output:

```
4
```

Albeit as mentioned `std::istringstream` is more "heavier" in terms of performance than writing your own loop.

Comment: THIS is the answer I was looking for. (strm >> word) isn't something I knew was possible, thank you!

Comment: Geez. `size_t n=0; bool spc=true; for (auto c:str) if (c == ' ') { spc=true; } else { if (spc) ++n; spc=false; }` -- The End. (Feel free to plagiarize)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You should make that an answer. The other answers are excessive (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard function `std::distance` with `std::istringstream` the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include  <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s( " This is a   test" );
    std::istringstream iss( s );

    auto count = std::distance( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( iss ),
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

    std::cout << count << '\n';                                
}
```

The program output is

```
4
```

If you want you can place the call of `std::distance` in a separate function like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include  <string>
#include <iterator>

size_t numWords( const std::string &s )
{
    std::istringstream iss( s );
    return std::distance( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( iss ),
                          std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( " This is a   test" );

    std::cout << numWords( s ) << '\n';                                
}
```

If separators can include other characters apart from white space characters as for example punctuations then you should use methods of the class `std::string`  or `std::string_view` `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

size_t numWords( const std::string_view s, std::string_view delim = " \t" )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( std::string_view::size_type pos = 0;
          ( pos = s.find_first_not_of( delim, pos ) ) != std::string_view::npos;
            pos = s.find_first_of( delim, pos ) )
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;        
}
 

int main()
{
    std::string s( "Is it a   test ? Yes ! Now we will run it ..." );

    std::cout << numWords( s, " \t!?.," ) << '\n';                                
}
```

The program output is

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily with regex

```cpp
int numWords(std::string str) 
{
    std::regex re("\\S+"); // or `[^ \t\n]+` to exactly match the question 
    return std::distance(
        std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re),
        std::sregex_iterator()
    );
}
```

Comment: This will work incorrectly because it will count words that are separated not only by white space characters. For example the phone number as 123-456-7890 will be counted as three words.

Answer (score 0):

Sam's comment made me write a function that does not allocate strings for words. But just creates string_views on the input string.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string_view> get_words(const std::string& input)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> words;

    // the first word begins at an alpha character
    auto begin_of_word = std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const char c) { return std::isalpha(c); });
    auto end_of_word = input.begin();
    auto end_of_input = input.end();

    // parse the whole string
    while (end_of_word != end_of_input)
    {
        // as long as you see text characters move end_of_word one back
        while ((end_of_word != end_of_input) && std::isalpha(*end_of_word)) end_of_word++;

        // create a string view from begin of word to end of word.
        // no new string memory will be allocated
        // std::vector will do some dynamic memory allocation to store string_view (metadata of word positions) 
        words.emplace_back(begin_of_word, end_of_word);

        // then skip all non readable characters.
        while ((end_of_word != end_of_input) && !std::isalpha(*end_of_word) ) end_of_word++;

        // and if we haven't reached the end then we are at the beginning of a new word.
        if ( end_of_word != input.end()) begin_of_word = end_of_word;
    }

    return words;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input{ "This, this   is a   test!" };
    auto words = get_words(input);

    for (const auto& word : words)
    {
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```